# java connection to VirtualBox Oracle server doesn't work

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, virtualbox

I've my development environment on MAC OS, NetBeans IDE, Wildfly server. My Oracle server is installed on a Virtual Box VM, by using the Oracle predefined VM.

The Virtual Box VM networking has been configured by using NAT and port 1521 forward.

I'm able to connect Oracle server by using SQLDeveloper with the following configuration, and it works.

[image]

The java connection has the following parameters:

```
jdbc.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE
jdbc.username = xxxxxxx
jdbc.password = zzzzzzz
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
```

and provides the following error:

```
08:11:12,534 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) Unable obtain JDBC Connection: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Errore di I/O: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
...
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `SQLDeveloper`  was installed on the Virtual Machine, hence `localhost` worked fine.
But you are trying to run code from your actual machine (not through VM) hence `localhost` is being resolved to your Mac machine not the VirtualBox machine.

Try one thing figure out the IP address of your virtual machine and put that in you config and retry.

**Or**

Try to bring your VM also on the same network by tweaking you network settings in Virtual Machine.

Comment: OP said he has configured port-forwarding.

Comment: I would start from Basic setup and keep advancing to next steps, so I can identify which step failed exactly.

Comment: SQLDeveloper is installed on guest machine (MAC OS). I tried also to do telnet localhost 1521 and it works, so the problem must be at java side, but I don't understand where ...

Comment: Your config looks fine. Try replacing your jdbc string with: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE  (two foreslash before localhost). Make sure you can connect with SQLDev using service_name (XE). SID is no longer recommended.